# Totally connected set

Tags: real-analysis

In my real analysis homework, I have the following definition: a subset $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n $ is said to be totally connected if for all $x \in X$ and all $r > 0$, $X\cap B(x;r)$ is connected. First it asks to show that a totally connected set is connected, which I did. Then it says, suppose $X$ is open. Show that $X$ is connected iff it is totally connected. But if $X = B((0,0);1)\backslash\{\,(x,0)\,; 0\le x\le 1\}\subset \mathbb{R^2}$, then X is open and connected but $X \cap B(a;r)$, with $a=(1/2,r/2)$ and $r>0$ is disconnected. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you've copied the definitions from your homework correctly, then what you say is quite right. As far as I know, "totally connected" is not a standard concept, so maybe the definition has been given incorrectly in the question.

Comment: I didn't copy, it was sent via email. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious before talking to the professor.

Comment: "Totally connected set" is how I translated the portuguese "conjunto totalmente conexo", so maybe that's not the standard name for this definition. But I also haven't found the same definition in English, so it's probably not standard as you say.

Comment: I don't think you have missed anything obvious. And thank you for teaching me a little Portuguese - "conjunto" means "set"?

Comment: Yes, that's right.